# How to pass byte array from postman

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, postman, webapi

I am working on a public API where user will send byte[] in parameter. I have implemented the API method and want to do the testing for it but If I am trying in postman then not able to send the byte[]. Getting bellow error

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "|e1896d86-412b7762126469ae.",
"errors": {
    "$": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Byte[]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
    ]
}
```

}

API method paramters

```
public IActionResult Upload(int clientId, string dtName, byte[] dtValues, bool append)
    {
 
}
```

Postman call

[image]

Comment: As a JSON array? [37, 80, ...]

Comment: i can use any format to pass as byte[].

Comment: JSON doesn't represent binary data, and hence not natively a byte array. You probably want to model as `int[]` instead to represent array of integers.

Comment: Hi @ArunSingh, i have shared multiple scenario and solution below. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, asp.net core **does not support** post **multiple parameters** from body, you need **put these parameters into a model** then you could post them from body.

Then, what you did should be post from query. But it seems does not support `byte[]` from query.

1. If you use **JSON.NET**, you could post `clientId`,`dtName` and `append` from **query** and post `dtValues` from **body** like below(Be sure your controller is declared with `[ApiController]`):

[image]

2. If you use `System.Text.Json`,with `Sytem.Text.Json` a byte array (`byte[]`) will be serialized as base64 string. They stated that they won't add support for `byte[]` to be serialized as number array in a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30456).

Custom JsonConverter:

```
public class ByteArrayConverter : JsonConverter<byte[]>
{
    public override byte[] Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        short[] sByteArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<short[]>(ref reader);
        byte[] value = new byte[sByteArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sByteArray.Length; i++)
        {
            value[i] = (byte)sByteArray[i];
        }

        return value;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, byte[] value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (var val in value)
        {
            writer.WriteNumberValue(val);
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Register it:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
     options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new ByteArrayConverter());
});
```

Test in Postman:

[image]

BTW, not sure **what is your scenario**, if you post the byte array is something like ***file***(**e.g:** image or .doc or .xlx file), you could use `IFormFile` and add `[FromForm]` before the parameter. Both `JSON.NET` or `System.Text.Json` supports receive `IFormFile`, no need custom JsonConverter here:

```
[Route("Upload")]
public IActionResult Upload(int clientId, string dtName, [FromForm]IFormFile dtValues, bool append)
{
        return Ok();
}
```

Post the data like below:
[image]

If you do not want to **separately** post them from **query** and **body**, you could **put them into a model** and post them from body.

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int clientId { get; set; }
    public string dtName { get; set; }
    public byte[] dtValues { get; set; }
    public bool append { get; set; }
}
```

Post in Postman:

**Note:** if you use `System.Text.Json`, you still need to custom JsonConverter like above option 2 I shared.

[image]

Comment: Great research! my customer want to send the data in file format or byte[] format. So we have to give both options. I am able to work with file but not from byte[]. I will try your answer/ thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass array and not string.

```
dtValues : [37,80]
```